# What is "plasma discharge"?

Tags: plasma-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering

I am trying to find the definition of "plasma discharge"? I googled and only found one useful site:https://www.ipp.mpg.de/ippcms/eng/pr/exptypen/tokamak/plasmaentladungen/index
(in magnetic confinement fusion research.)

But I am still not sure which process this term refers to. Does it refer to the process when the atoms are ionized? Or the process when the fusion reaction occurs?

Also, I want to know what is the difference between "plasma discharge" and "glow discharge"(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glow_discharge).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One definition of glow discharge is "Glow discharge plasma is formed when the voltage applied on a low-pressure gas exceeds its breakdown voltage and causes its ionization." There are many other ways to make plasmas, and all plasmas conduct electricity (charges).

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you for your reply. But I am still wondering what is "plasma discharge"?

Comment: Plasmas all glow through recombination of electrons and ions as well as relaxation of excited atomic/ionic states. How the plasma is actually formed can vary dramatically.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you. I heard the term "plasma discharge" in the news and papers about nuclear fusion experiments. So how about this one?